# Determining if a basis consists of eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

**Problem:** Let $V = P_1(R)$ be a vectorspace, and let $T(a+bx) = (6a - 6b) + (12a-11b)x$ be a linear operator on $V$. Let $\beta = \left\{ 3+4x, 2+3x \right\}$ be a basis for $V$. Compute $[T]_{\beta}$ and determine whether $\beta$ is a basis consisting of eigenvectors of $T$.

**Attempt at solution:** We have $T(3+4x) = (18-24) + (36-44)x = -6 -8x$ and $T(2+3x) = (12-18) + (24-33)x = -6 -9x$.

Furthermore, since $ -6 - 8x = -2(3+4x) + 0(2+3x)$ and $-6-9x = 0(3+4x) -3(2+3x)$, we have that \begin{align*} [T]_{\beta} = \begin{pmatrix} -2 & 0 \\ 0 & -3 \end{pmatrix}. \end{align*}
Now I'm not sure how to determine if $\beta$ consists of eigenvectors. I let $v_1 = 3+4x$ and $v_2 = 2+3x$ be the basisvectors.

Then \begin{align*} L_A(v_1) = \begin{pmatrix} -2 & 0 \\ 0 & -3 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -6 \\ -12 \end{pmatrix}. \end{align*} Then must I ask myself if there is a $\lambda$ (eigenvalue) such that $L_A (v_1) = \lambda v_1$? This is not the case here, so the conclusion is that $\beta$ doesn't consist of eigenvectors?

Is this the right approach or did I go wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

You're doing fine. You've written it out already. As you've pointed out yourself,
\begin{align}
T(3x + 4) &= -2(3x + 4) \\
T(2x + 3) &= -3(2x + 3).
\end{align}
By definition, $3x + 4$ is an eigenvector for $T$, corresponding to eigenvalue $-2$, and $2x + 3$ is an eigenvector for $T$, corresponding to eigenvalue $-3$. That proves they are eigenvectors, *by definition*.

Alternatively, the fact that you got a diagonal matrix for the matrix of $T$ under this basis, tells you that the basis consisted of eigenvectors. (Just think about how you construct the columns for this matrix, and you might be able to see why this works!)

Comment: I see, thanks. Also, I have another question. If I'm given a linear map, like in the above example, how can I find $L_A$ then? In other words: How do I find the matrix that represents this linear map? Do I just compute $[T]_{\beta}$ like I did above?

Comment: What do you mean by $L_A$? There are (almost always) infinitely many matrices that represent a given linear map. For each basis $\beta$, you can compute $[T]_\beta$ just as you have: by finding the image of the basis vectors in $\beta$, and then writing the resulting vectors as coordinate vectors in terms of $\beta$.